# Heroku Not Detecting Ruby Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I put the ruby version 2.3.1 in my gemfile, but Heroku keeps using 2.4.4. How do I make it so Heroku recognizes the version specified in the gemfile?

Comment: Have you checked this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions,  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions

Comment: Ruby 2.3.1 now supported on Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/879

Comment: @praaveen The date of that article is 2+ years ago and corresponds directly with the official 2.3.1 release. Unless you have a reason not to, use the latest version in the series (2.3.7 in your case).

Comment: yes i've read those links. i've specified the version in my gemfile. it still does not recognize it and defaults to using 2.4.4

Comment: did you run `bundle`, commit your changes, then deploy?

Comment: How did you define the Ruby version in your Gefule?

Comment: I wrote ruby "2.3.1"

Comment: @xyz123 Did you try to specify ruby version in `.ruby-version` file in the root of the rails app?

Comment: yes i tried that too

Answer (score 0):

try to use the heroku console by typing heroku run "ruby -v" and give command to use which version of ruby you want him to

Answer (score 0):

You are probably on the `heroku-18` stack which it the current default. Please note that Ruby `2.3.x` is not available on [this stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions).

You have two options:

1. Update your Ruby version to a more recent version or
2. Downgrade Heroku to use an older stack.

Given that the maintenance phase for Ruby 2.3.x has [ended anyway](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2018/03/28/ruby-2-3-7-released/) I would suggest updating our application to use at least Ruby `2.4.4`.

Comment: I'm using heroku 16 and still have the same issue. Unable to upgrade ruby version due to other reasons